# Converting Excel 2003 Workbook to Excel 97 in C#

Tags: c#, excel

How would I convert and Excel 2003 Open XML Workbook to Excel 97 Format using C#?

Comment: OpenXml is Excel 2007, not Excel 2003.

Comment: This post has a duplicate at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606560. One of the two should be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Is it simply data or are there formulas and VBA? If it is just data you could read in the file as XML and do use an XSLT to convert the data to a CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

Using Visual Studio Tools for Office, open the workbook and then do a SaveAs, select Excel 97 as the format type.

Answer (score 0):

You could try following:

1. Start Excel
2. Start Macro recording mode
3. Open an open-xml workbook.
4. Save it as Excel 97.
5. Stop Macro recording mode.
6. View the generated VBA code and port it to C# using the VS tools for Office mentioned by Nathan.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Excel 2007 Open XML? There is no Excel 2003 Open XML format. There is an Excel 2003 SpreadsheetML format which is an XML format that is incomplete as well as being a dead end format.

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) can read and write both Excel 97-2003 (xls) workbooks and Excel 2007 Open XML (xlsx) workbooks and will convert between the two formats.

There is a [free evaluation](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx) if you want to try it out.

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC